# How to make a field readonly for a particular group in Open Erp 7?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7, usergroups

I have a field which i want to make it readonly for all the user from a group, lets say base.group_userA. any other users will be able to edit and save the field. How do i do that in openerp?. I have already set all CRUD access rights for all users.

```
'WO_NOTES' : fields.text("Description"),
```

in xml

```
<field name="WO_NOTES"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, only I wanted to show fields only to users in a group. I solved this by inheriting the view and made changes to the specific group.

In your case it should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
<record model="ir.ui.view"  id="view_id">
    <field name="name">view.id</field>
    <field name="model">your.model</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="id_of_inherited_view"/>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_userA') ])]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="WO_NOTES" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Hope this helps!

--- A little edit to clarify a little my answer ---

I assume that you have your form view, working fine to all users (with the WO_NOTES editable to all users). With this inheritance, the change will take place only to users belonging to `base.group_userA`, changing it's attribute to readonly (only to this field and only to users from this group).

The `<field name="WO_NOTES" position="attributes"> <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute></field>` part will locate the field in the parent view and make it readonly. The `<field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_userA') ])]"/>` limits this change to the specified group.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but what im looking for is to make only one field readonly, to a particular group, not all the fields in that view, and may i know why do you need a button?

Comment: You are right, it not a button, its a field (copied it from my code and in my case I was hidding buttons, and forgot to change it to "field"). I edited my answer, adding also some more clarification about this inheritance.

Comment: it doesn't work, there are no errors, but when i update the module, it keeps on loading and never updates.

Comment: Make sure the view_id you are creating doesn't already exist. Or try create a new DB and install your module.

Comment: i created a new view with new id and it works now, thanks alot!